# primaryStage cannot be resolved to a variable:,When using in other class: JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I know There are many Questions related to this particular error, But I couldn't Find a solution that fits my Error.

So What I am doing is creating a javaFX Application and using the `Modality` library so that I can create a subwindow which opens always above of the Primary Stage. But the Error I am getting that I am not able set the primaryStage Variable inside the `initOwner()` function because of the `Scope` issue as `PrimaryStage` is outside the scope of `SubModal` Class.

let me put some code to make things clear..

```
//SubModal Class
class SubModal extends singleModal {

    SubModal()
    {
        Stage subStage1 = new Stage();
        subStage1.setTitle("New Stage1");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        Button btn2 = new Button("Button: Stage1");
        root.getChildren().add(btn2);
        btn2.setOnAction(eve-> System.out.println("Clicked on Stage 1 Button"));
        subStage1.initOwner(primaryStage);
        subStage1.initModality(Modality.NONE);
        subStage1.setScene(scene1);
        subStage1.show();
    }
}

//SingleModal Class
public class singleModal extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("PrimaryStage");

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 200);
        Button btn = new Button("Open New Stage");
        btn.setOnAction(eve-> new NewStage());
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

From the above code..

`subStage1.initOwner(primaryStage);`

This particular line Shows the Error

> primaryStage cannot be resolved to a variable

I Know it's because `PrimaryStage()` is not available in the subModal Class.

So My question is that How Can I fix this issue in JavaFX. How can I bring the `primaryStage` Value in the `SubModal` Class so that I can run this Code ErrorFree

Comment: parameter passing/inheritence is not specific to javafx, it's just plain java - looks like you want to read and understand a basic tutorial on java :) Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra.  nice suggestion. I know I am newbie to the JAVA lang.but. have got this specific task to do on urgent basis.

Comment: What is the functionality you need ? Is all you want is to _"create a subwindow which opens always above of the Primary Stage"_  ?

Comment: yes . sort of that thing I want. @c0der.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the needed functionality ("*create a subwindow which opens always above of the Primary Stage*") there is no need to extend `singleModal`. 
Here is an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SingleModal extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {

        Stage subStage1 = new Stage();
        subStage1.setTitle("New Stage1");

        Button btn2 = new Button("Button: Stage1");
        FlowPane root2 = new FlowPane();
        root2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root2.getChildren().add(btn2);
        btn2.setOnAction(eve-> System.out.println("Clicked on Stage 1 Button"));
        subStage1.initOwner(primaryStage);
        subStage1.initModality(Modality.NONE);
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root2, 300, 200);
        subStage1.setScene(scene1);

        primaryStage.setTitle("PrimaryStage");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 200);
        Button btn = new Button("Open New Stage");
        btn.setOnAction(eve->  subStage1.show());
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what u want is just add the code in the start method. I have no idea what the SubModule class is for.

Further Modality is not a library. Maybe call it a feature.

Maybe that example helps http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/08/javafx-example-modality.html .

So add

```
Stage subStage1 = new Stage();
    subStage1.setTitle("New Stage1");
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    Button btn2 = new Button("Button: Stage1");
    root.getChildren().add(btn2);
    btn2.setOnAction(eve-> System.out.println("Clicked on Stage 1 Button"));
    subStage1.initOwner(primaryStage);
    subStage1.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    subStage1.setScene(scene1);
    subStage1.show();
```

to the end of the start method.